# .htaccess to rewrite one specific file to another specific file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

All I need to do is rewrite a .js file to a .php file, so when someone visits "lib/rary.js" they actually get "lib/rary.php".

This is what I'm trying:

```
RewriteCond ^lib/rary.php lib/rary.js [L]
```

But it's giving me a server config error.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: RewriteCond's are conditions that match something, they are not the rewrite itself.  Typically you have one or more RewriteCond's followed by a rewrite rule.  In this case it looks like you simply need the rewrite rule.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I really don't know anything about this.

Comment: Did you try RewriteRule ^lib/rary\.js lib/rary.php [L]?

Answer (score 0):

From gview:

```
RewriteRule ^lib/rary\.js lib/rary.php [L]
```

It worked!